# As a Canadian citizen and Italian Resident, do I need a visa to carry out remote contractual work for a UK company?

Tags: uk-visa, canadian-citizens, italian-citizens

Are there any visa requirements as an Italian resident who would be working remotely from Italy but for a UK company? The work would be part-time and of a consulting nature. If so, I would appreciate any links to official documentation on the rulings for this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a UK work visa to work in the UK.  You won't be working in the UK, so you won't need a UK work visa.

If you are not yet authorized to work in Italy then you will need to get an Italian work visa or work permit or other authorization.

Your client in the UK may be reluctant to pay you directly for fear of falling afoul of labor laws and, especially, payroll obligations.  If that is the case then you will need to set up a company or register as a sole proprietor (details vary in different countries) so you can handle those responsibilities yourself and establish a business-to-business relationship with your client.